# php - copying some part of string

Tags: php, string

how can i get some part of string (in symbols).
For example:

```
$string = 'one two three';
$numSymbols = 7;
 %what should I do%
$res_string = 'one two';
```

Help, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the [substr](http://php.net/substr) function, I'd say.

In your case, here is an example :

```
$string = 'one two three';
$numSymbols = 7;

$res_string = substr($string, 0, $numSymbols);
var_dump($res_string);
```

And you'll get :

```
string 'one two' (length=7)
```

Parameters :

- the string to extract from
- the position of the first character ; ie, 0, if you want to start at the beginning of the string
- the number of characters you want : 7

Comment: @arbales : that's the problem with trying to type too fast :-( Thanks! I've edited to correct that typo (and a few others... )

Answer (score 2):

use php method [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$string = 'one two three';
$numSymbols = 7;
$res_string = substr($string, 0, $numSymbols);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [substr](http://www.php.net/substr)()

Example:

```
$string = 'one two three';
$res_string = substr($string, 0, 7);// $res_string == 'one two'
```